# MySQL Left Join Statement Duplicating records

Tags: mysql, sql

The solution is such:

```
SELECT
    invoice.invoice_id,
    IFNULL(
        SUM(refund.amount),
        0
    ) AS refund_amount
FROM
    invoice
    INNER JOIN invoice_status ON invoice_status.invoice_status_id = invoice.status_id
    LEFT JOIN reservation ON reservation.reservation_id = invoice.reservation_id
    LEFT JOIN reservation_status ON reservation_status.reservation_status_id = reservation.reservation_status_id
    LEFT JOIN refund_invoice ON refund_invoice.invoice_id = invoice.invoice_id
    LEFT JOIN refund ON refund.refund_id = refund_invoice.refund_id
WHERE
    invoice_status.invoice_status in ('Paid', 'Partially Refunded')
    AND invoice.has_been_dispersed = 0
    AND reservation_status.reservation_status in ('Closed', 'Ended', 'Cancelled')
GROUP BY
    invoice.invoice_id;
    
    
    
    
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE payments 
SELECT
    invoice.invoice_id,
    IFNULL(
        SUM(payment.amount),
        0
    ) AS payment_amount
FROM
    invoice
    INNER JOIN invoice_status ON invoice_status.invoice_status_id = invoice.status_id
    LEFT JOIN reservation ON reservation.reservation_id = invoice.reservation_id
    LEFT JOIN reservation_status ON reservation_status.reservation_status_id = reservation.reservation_status_id
    LEFT JOIN payment_invoice ON payment_invoice.invoice_id = invoice.invoice_id
    LEFT JOIN payment ON payment.payment_id = payment_invoice.payment_id
WHERE
    invoice_status.invoice_status in ('Paid', 'Partially Refunded')
    AND invoice.has_been_dispersed = 0
    AND reservation_status.reservation_status in ('Closed', 'Ended', 'Cancelled')
GROUP BY
    invoice.invoice_id;
    
    

SELECT
    invoice.invoice_id,
    invoice.company_id,
    invoice_status.invoice_status,
    invoice.total AS invoice_total_amount,
    IFNULL(
        reservation.reservation_id, 'ADHOC INVOICE'
    ) AS reservation_id,
    refund_amount,
    payment_amount,
    invoice.payment_processor_fee,
    invoice.vquip_fee,
    payment_amount - refund_amount AS gross_amount_to_be_dispersed,
    payment_amount - refund_amount 
     - IFNULL(
        SUM(invoice.vquip_fee),
        0
    ) 
    - IFNULL(
        CASE WHEN invoice.charge_customers_payment_processing_fee = 0 THEN IFNULL(
            invoice.payment_processor_fee, 0
        ) WHEN invoice.charge_customers_payment_processing_fee = 1 THEN 0 ELSE 0 END,
        0
    ) AS amount_to_be_dispersed,
    invoice.charge_customers_payment_processing_fee
FROM
    invoice
    INNER JOIN invoice_status ON invoice_status.invoice_status_id = invoice.status_id
    left join payments on payments.invoice_id = invoice.invoice_id
    left join refunds on refunds.invoice_id = invoice.invoice_id
    LEFT JOIN reservation ON reservation.reservation_id = invoice.reservation_id
    LEFT JOIN reservation_status ON reservation_status.reservation_status_id = reservation.reservation_status_id
WHERE
    invoice_status.invoice_status in ('Paid', 'Partially Refunded')
    AND invoice.has_been_dispersed = 0
    AND reservation_status.reservation_status in ('Closed', 'Ended', 'Cancelled')
GROUP BY
    invoice.invoice_id,
    invoice.total,
    invoice.reservation_id,
    invoice_status.invoice_status,
    invoice.charge_customers_payment_processing_fee,
    invoice.payment_processor_fee,
    invoice.vquip_fee,
    invoice.company_id; 



    
    
DROP TEMPORARY TABLE refunds;
DROP TEMPORARY TABLE payments;
```

---

I am write a sql statement to select all payments and refunds that are on an invoice. With the below basic statement i am seeing duplicate columns of data when i expect NULL where it should be null.

This query returns the below results:

```
SELECT
    invoice.invoice_id,
    refund.amount as refund_amount,
    payment.amount as payment_amount
FROM
    invoice
    LEFT JOIN refund_invoice ON refund_invoice.invoice_id = invoice.invoice_id
    LEFT JOIN refund ON refund.refund_id = refund_invoice.refund_id
    LEFT JOIN payment_invoice ON payment_invoice.invoice_id = invoice.invoice_id
    LEFT JOIN payment ON payment.payment_id = payment_invoice.payment_id
where invoice.company_id = 59
and invoice.reservation_id = 1157
```

| Invoice ID | Refund Amount | Payment Amount |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1277 | 222.5 | 222.5 |
| 1277 | 277.5 | 222.5 |
| 1277 | 222.5 | 343.76 |
| 1277 | 277.5 | 343.76 |

I would be expecting where i can select the rows by refund and payment seperately rather joined. Something like below. This way i can SUM the totals with out duplicates.

| Invoice ID | Refund Amount | Payment Amount |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1277 | NULL | 222.5 |
| 1277 | 222.5 | NULL |
| 1277 | NULL | 343.76 |
| 1277 | 277.5 | NULL |

Here is the final query that i would like to use. This works when there aren't the same amount of payments/refunds records for for the invoice.

```
SELECT
    invoice.invoice_id,
    invoice.company_id,
    invoice_status.invoice_status,
    invoice.total AS invoice_total_amount,
    IFNULL(
        reservation.reservation_id, 'ADHOC INVOICE'
    ) AS reservation_id,
    IFNULL(
        SUM(refund.amount),
        0
    ) AS refund_amount,
    IFNULL(
        SUM(payment.amount),
        0
    ) AS payment_amount,
    invoice.payment_processor_fee,
    invoice.vquip_fee,
    IFNULL(
        SUM(payment.amount),
        0
    ) - IFNULL(
        SUM(refund.amount),
        0
    ) AS gross_amount_to_be_dispersed,
    IFNULL(
        SUM(payment.amount),
        0
    ) - IFNULL(
        SUM(refund.amount),
        0
    ) 
     - IFNULL(
        SUM(invoice.vquip_fee),
        0
    ) 
    - IFNULL(
        CASE WHEN invoice.charge_customers_payment_processing_fee = 0 THEN IFNULL(
            invoice.payment_processor_fee, 0
        ) WHEN invoice.charge_customers_payment_processing_fee = 1 THEN 0 ELSE 0 END,
        0
    ) AS amount_to_be_dispersed,
    invoice.charge_customers_payment_processing_fee
FROM
    invoice
    INNER JOIN invoice_status ON invoice_status.invoice_status_id = invoice.status_id
    LEFT JOIN reservation ON reservation.reservation_id = invoice.reservation_id
    LEFT JOIN reservation_status ON reservation_status.reservation_status_id = reservation.reservation_status_id
    LEFT JOIN refund_invoice ON refund_invoice.invoice_id = invoice.invoice_id
    LEFT JOIN refund ON refund.refund_id = refund_invoice.refund_id
    LEFT JOIN payment_invoice ON payment_invoice.invoice_id = invoice.invoice_id
    LEFT JOIN payment ON payment.payment_id = payment_invoice.payment_id
WHERE
    invoice_status.invoice_status in ('Paid', 'Partially Refunded')
    AND (
        payment.processor_payment_id IS NOT NULL || refund.processor_refund_id IS NOT NULL
    )
    AND invoice.has_been_dispersed = 0
    AND reservation_status.reservation_status in ('Closed', 'Ended', 'Cancelled')
GROUP BY
    invoice.invoice_id,
    invoice.total,
    invoice.reservation_id,
    invoice_status.invoice_status,
    invoice.charge_customers_payment_processing_fee,
    invoice.payment_processor_fee,
    invoice.vquip_fee,
    invoice.company_id
```

Notes -
invoice table can have many refunds and many payments
invoice_refund and invoice_payment join the refund and payments records to an invoice.

Comment: This is not how sets work, unfortunately. You have to do the summing up in subqueries before joining them to the invoice table.

Comment: ah i was thinking this but hoping for mySQL magic. Thanks for the response.

Comment: @Shadow I added the solved query. Thanks for the insight on this

Comment: Finally somebody appreciating a duplicate link!